# plt.show() not executing properly

Tags: python, matplotlib

Currently, I am attempting to follow along with a Sentdex YouTube tutorial video (https://www.youtube.com/watchv=cExOVprMlQg&list=PLQVvvaa0QuDe6ZBtkCNWNUbdaBo2vA4RO), however I am running into some difficulties with plt.show(). I have written this script nearly verbatim as detailed in this video and I have turned to StackOverflow to update any syntax, yet I have not been able to actually view this graph. Nothing comes up when I run the script, the shell just spits out '>>'.  I have changed backends, unistalled, upgraded and reinstalled matplotlib. I've also tried this script on the exact version of Python seen in this video as well as 3.6.1 and a few others on OS X and Windows 10 via Parallels - still running into the same issue.

Here is my code thus far:

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as mticker
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import numpy as np
import pylab


def graphRawFX():
    date, bid, ask = np.loadtext('GBPUSD1d.txt', unpack=True,
                                 delimiter='-',
                                 converters={0: mdates.strpdate2numb('%Y%m%d%H%M%S')})

    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,7))

    ax1 = plt.subplot2grid((40,40), (0), rowspan=40, colspan=40)
    ax1.plot(date, bid)
    ax1.plot(date, ask)

    ax1.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdate.DateFormatter('%Y-%m-%d %H:#M:#S'))
    for label in ax1.axis,get_xticklabels():
        label.set_rotation(45) 

    ply.gca().get_yaxis().get_major_formatter().set_useOffset(False)


    plt.grid(True)
    plt.show()
    pylab.show()
```

Any thoughts on a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You defined a function, which plots. But you never call the function! Your script is empty from python's perspective.

Add `graphRawFX()` at the end, without any indentation to actually call the function.

If this code is by any means incomplete and not your issue, check your install and clean up the code. The whole import pylab thing looks unwanted. Also `ply` does not exist and so on. Start with the basics, the official examples and the docs, not with some yt-video which uses tons of (advanced) stuff.

Comment: Here was my output after following your suggestion: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/michaelsylvia/Documents/sentdexi.py", line 29, in <module>
    graphRawFX()
  File "/Users/michaelsylvia/Documents/sentdexi.py", line 10, in graphRawFX
    date, bid, ask = np.loadtext('GBPUSD1d.txt', unpack=True,
AttributeError: module 'numpy' has no attribute 'loadtext'                          The import pylab was an answer to a similar question. I realize I am facing a steep learning curve, with that being said I am unsure as the code wouldn't run under identical circumstances.

Comment: The function was either renamed or your code is bogus (there is loadtxt). Seriously, follow my recommendations: don't copy-paste old code (which might not run with an install from today) from some unknown source. Take the official docs of matplotlib as base, and try simple things first!

Comment: Yes, start much much *much* simpler, and take your time. Maybe finding a more up to date video would help, or more basic python tutorials (forget matplotlib and just focus on python for a bit)

Answer (score 0):

I have it working (mac OS). Just try to copy paste to see if there's some typing problem. (it was working without "import pylab" and the "pylab.show()" I have just put it to have the same code you have.

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as mticher
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import numpy as np
import pylab

def graphRawFX():
        date,bid,ask = np.loadtxt('GBPUSD1d.txt', unpack=True, delimiter=',',converters={0:mdates.strpdate2num('%Y%m%d%H%M%S')})

        fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,7))
        ax1 = plt.subplot2grid((40,40), (0,0), rowspan=40, colspan=40)

        ax1.plot(date,bid)
        ax1.plot(date,ask)
        plt.gca().get_yaxis().get_major_formatter().set_useOffset(False)

        ax1.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
        for label in ax1.xaxis.get_ticklabels() :
                label.set_rotation(45)

        ax1_2=ax1.twinx()
        ax1_2.fill_between(date,0, (ask-bid),facecolor='g',alpha=.3)

        plt.subplots_adjust(bottom=.23)

        plt.grid(True)
        plt.show()
        pylab.show()

graphRawFX()
```